# MediaCodec.Callback handle IllegalStateException from MediaExtractor

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I am using `MediaCodec` in asynchronous mode to transcode a video based on the example by [mstorsjo](https://github.com/mstorsjo/android-decodeencodetest/blob/master/src/com/example/decodeencodetest/ExtractDecodeEditEncodeMuxTest.java). With some video files I am getting `IllegalStateException`'s thrown when I call either `MediaExtractor.advance()` or `MediaExtractor.getSampleTime()`. E.g. in my audio decoder:

```
MediaCodec decoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(type);
decoder.setCallback(new MediaCodec.Callback() {
    public void onInputBufferAvailable(@NonNull MediaCodec codec, int index) {
        ByteBuffer decoderInputBuffer = codec.getInputBuffer(index);
        while (!mExtractorDone) {
            int size = mExtractor.readSampleData(decoderInputBuffer, 0);
            long presentationTimeUs = mExtractor.getSampleTime();
            boolean queuedInputBuffer = false;
            if (size >= 0) {
                codec.queueInputBuffer(
                        index,
                        0,
                        size,
                        presentationTimeUs,
                        mExtractor.getSampleFlags());
                queuedInputBuffer = true;
            }
            mExtractorDone = !mExtractor.advance();
            if (mExtractorDone) {
                queueEOS();
            }
            if (queuedInputBuffer) {
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    ...
});
decoder.configure(inputFormat, null, null, 0);
decoder.start();
```

And similarly in my video decoder, which is run in a separate [HandlerThread](https://github.com/mstorsjo/android-decodeencodetest/blob/master/src/com/example/decodeencodetest/ExtractDecodeEditEncodeMuxTest.java#L551).

Is there a way I can catch all exceptions thrown in the `MediaCodec.Callback` and pass them back to the main [awaitEncode](https://github.com/mstorsjo/android-decodeencodetest/blob/master/src/com/example/decodeencodetest/ExtractDecodeEditEncodeMuxTest.java#L367) function, so I can close everything and exit nicely? Should I be putting `try catch`s around every callback and then `notify` the main processing thread?

It would be great to figure out what is causing the original `IllegalStateException`, but I would also feel more comfortable knowing all problems with my video transcoder were being caught and explained to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best solution so far is to just wrap everything in a `try catch` block. I use a utility class that extends `MediaCodec.Callback`:

```
public abstract class SafeMediaCodecCallback extends MediaCodec.Callback {

    private final OnExceptionListener exceptionListener;

    public SafeMediaCodecCallback(OnExceptionListener exceptionListener) {
        this.exceptionListener = exceptionListener;
    }

    @Override
    public final void onInputBufferAvailable(@NonNull MediaCodec mediaCodec, int i) {
        try {
            onInputBufferAvailableSafe(mediaCodec, i);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            handleException(exception);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public final void onOutputBufferAvailable(@NonNull MediaCodec mediaCodec, int i, @NonNull MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo) {
        try {
            onOutputBufferAvailableSafe(mediaCodec, i, bufferInfo);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            handleException(exception);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public final void onError(@NonNull MediaCodec mediaCodec, @NonNull MediaCodec.CodecException e) {
        handleException(e);
    }

    @Override
    public final void onOutputFormatChanged(@NonNull MediaCodec mediaCodec, @NonNull MediaFormat mediaFormat) {
        try {
            onOutputFormatChangedSafe(mediaCodec, mediaFormat);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            handleException(exception);
        }
    }

    private void handleException(Exception e) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            if (e instanceof CodecException) {
                CodecException codecExc = (CodecException) e;

                if (codecExc.isTransient()) {
                    // We'll let transient exceptions go
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        exceptionListener.onException(e);
    }

    public abstract void onInputBufferAvailableSafe(@NonNull MediaCodec mediaCodec, int i);

    public abstract void onOutputBufferAvailableSafe(@NonNull MediaCodec mediaCodec, int i, @NonNull MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo);

    public abstract void onOutputFormatChangedSafe(@NonNull MediaCodec mediaCodec, @NonNull MediaFormat mediaFormat);

}
```

And then I can bubble exceptions back up to the top thread, and if we can't recover, kill all the threads, tidy up, and throw the original `Exception`.

Comment: Hi, it's late but have you found any way from recovering the media codec after IllegalStateException? bcz try-catch slow down the processing and the frames drawn were scattered.